# How to make a loop that pauses for 5 minutes after each set of 25 iterations until its done?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, wait

It's more complicated than it sounds. At least to me anyway. So far I just have a for loop with 25 iterations and a sleep. Maybe a combination of a while loop and a for loop? Or viceversa?

```
for (int i = 0; i<25; i++){
// my code
Thread.sleep(300000);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Guessing something like this

```
int count = 0;

for(loop here)
{
    count++;
    if(count == 25)
    {
        Tread.Sleep(300000);
        count = 0;
    }
    //do stuff here
}
```